# R group by approximate values

Tags: r, group-by, approximation

I have a R dataframe (250,000 rows) that some data looks like this:

```
df = data.frame(X = c(1000.005, 1000.7, 1200, 1566, 1766.55, 1767.30, 33.45, 33.25, 400.67, 400.77), Y = c(38.6, 38.4, 32.0, 32.01, 39.99, 39.20, 12.21, 12.11, 33.81, 33.91), Angle = c(50, 36, 27, 77, 26, 34, 29, 14, 37, 55))
```

So my goal is to group the data based on the approximation of both the X and Y value, with the difference that is no more than 1. For the data set shown above, the group arrangement will look like this:

```
data.frame(X = c(1000.005, 1000.7, 1200, 1566, 1766.55, 1767.30, 33.45, 33.25, 400.67, 400.77), Y = c(38.6, 38.4, 32.0, 32.01, 39.99, 39.20, 12.21, 12.11, 33.81, 33.91), Angle = c(50, 36, 27, 77, 26, 34, 29, 14, 37, 55), group = c(1,1, 2, 3, 4,4, 5, 5, 6, 6))
```

Is there a function in R that I can do group by rows by setting their differences (in my case, the difference will be 1)?

Comment: How large is "very large"? 50000 rows? 5000000 rows?

Comment: You may need to further specify what your goal is. For example, if I have data c(.9,1.5,2), how would I group these? Would .9 and 1.5 be in a group? Or 1.5 and 2? It cannot be that .9 and 2 are in the group because the distance is too large. How do you go about choosing this? Maybe look into clustering functions? Kmeans is a popular one.

Comment: I think you're talking about *clustering*, and there are plenty of text books and graduate-level courses that talk a lot about the topic. You can start with `kmeans` (within base R `stats` package), though it is not always the best (e.g., you must know how many clusters there are a priori). If you do `kmeans(dat[,c("X","Y")], centers = 4)`, you'll notice that it groups the top 3 are together; if you use `centers = 6` (your presumption), it *sometimes* differs from your groups (`kmeans` is stochastic due to the problem-space).

Comment: So my data set has about 250,000 rows. Will the kmeans still be practical in this case?

Comment: @doubled good points but I think most of them are only in duplicate, so let's just rule out the triplicate or more for now.

Comment: @kelvinfrog see my response

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a bit confusing, even with your comments, so I'll share some possible solutions.

Even if you are sure that every observation has a corresponding observation that is 'closest' to it, how do you define distance? Standard euclidean distance? But if every pair truly has a 'duplicate,' then why not just look at the values that have the closest, say, X value, and if there somehow is a tie between two, then look at the Y values? Or the other way around? If there are truly unique pairs of observations, any approach should yield the same answer. So just pick the easiest, and create a matrix of distances, and pick the minimum distance for each, and if for the jth observation, the ith observation has the minimum distance, then you know those form a pair. If you want to use both (X,Y), just use the standard euclidean distance.

Next there's the question of dataset size. 250,000 is fairly large, so using `dist` is probably not going to work. Honestly, given the above, I'd recommend you write a for loop where for the ith observation, if the jth observation is the closest, then you form a pair for them, and update the dataset you're searching over to remove them. It won't be pretty, but should run fairly quickly. Let us know if you have trouble with that.

Finally, as pointed out in the comments, the standard approach is probably to use some clustering approach. Maybe let the cluster size be equal to half the dataset size? You could even do a stepwise cluster approach where you specify half the dataset size at each step, look at within groups, take the pairs that are smallest, and then get an updated dataset that you again cluster on, and repeat until you get unique pairings.

With 250,000 rows, both of these approaches should really not be too much of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your data size is still computationally tractable using grouping. Here is a slightly messy `data.table` approach.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
group <- df[,ID := 1:.N][
  ,df[abs(X - .SD[,X]) < 1 & abs(Y - .SD[,Y]) < 1,.(ID2 = ID)],by = ID,.SDcols = c("X","Y")][
  ,.(df[ID,],df[ID2,])][
    ,Distance := sqrt((X-X.1)^2+(Y-Y.1)^2)][
      Distance <= 1,][
        !duplicated(ID.1),rleid(ID)]

df[,`:=`(Group = group, ID = NULL)]
df
#           X     Y Angle Group
# 1: 1000.005 38.60    50     1
# 2: 1000.700 38.40    36     1
# 3: 1200.000 32.00    27     2
# 4: 1566.000 32.01    77     3
# 5: 1766.550 39.99    26     4
# 6: 1767.300 39.20    34     5
# 7:   33.450 12.21    29     6
# 8:   33.250 12.11    14     6
# 9:  400.670 33.81    37     7
#10:  400.770 33.91    55     7
```

First, we subset the dataset itself for rows which are within 1 for both `X` and `Y`. Points can't possibly be closer than 1 if they are more than 1 in either dimension. We use `.SDcols` to only subset `.SD` for the columns we care about. Next, we bind together the rows. Then, we calculate the distance with the formula for euclidian distance manually. Next, we select rows that are within 1. The rows are ordered by `ID` from a previous step, so we can use `rleid` with `!duplicated` to make groups. Then just add that back to the original data, and you're done.

You'll know if it will work based on how long and how much memory this takes:

```
df[,ID := 1:.N][,df[abs(X - .SD[,X]) < 1 & abs(Y - .SD[,Y]) < 1,.(ID2 = ID)],by = ID,.SDcols = c("X","Y")]
```

Note that your expected output may have an error because the distance between points 5 and 6 is 1.089:

```
dist(rbind(c(1766.550,39.99),c(1767.300,39.20)))
#         1
#2 1.089312
```